# PHP - Check part of the string using substr() and then conditional - behaving strange

Tags: php, string, substring

First of all, for some reasons (such as the string can be of many types) I can't use the `explode()` function in one of my project. Where I'm getting a string like: "##% off". So to check whether it's *THIS* type of string, I want to check whether it contains the word "off". I'm trying to use the substring to get the tail part of the string, and then I was ashamed, it's giving me the answer "No" always.

I'm testing with this:

```
<?php
echo $string1 = '05% off'. '<br/>';
echo $string2 = '03% Off'. '<br/>';
echo $string3 = '50% OFF'. '<br/>';
echo $string4 = '50% oFf'. '<br/>';
echo '<hr/>';
echo $firstsub = substr( $string1, 4 );
echo $secondsub = substr( $string2, 4 );
echo $threesub = substr( $string3, 4 );
echo $foursub = substr( $string3, 4 );
echo '<br/>';
echo substr( $string1, 0, 2 ) . '<br/>';
echo substr( $string2, 0, 2 ) . '<br/>';
echo substr( $string3, 0, 2 ) . '<br/>';
echo substr( $string4, 0, 2 ) . '<br/>';
echo '<hr/>';
echo '<h2>TESTING</h2>';
if( strtolower( $firstsub ) == 'off' ) { echo "Yes" . '<br/>'; } else { echo "No" . '<br/>'; }
if( strtolower( $secondsub ) == 'off' ) { echo "Yes" . '<br/>'; } else { echo "No" . '<br/>'; }
if( strtolower( $threesub ) == 'off' ) { echo "Yes" . '<br/>'; } else { echo "No" . '<br/>'; }
if( strtolower( $foursub ) == 'off' ) { echo "Yes" . '<br/>'; } else { echo "No" . '<br/>'; }
?>
```

I can't understand why this is happening?

Comment: why not simply use a regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$string1` = `05% off<br/>` So when you are doing the `substr()` `$firstsub` is equal to `off<br/>` not just `off`

You can see this if you do a `var_dump()`

```
echo $string1 = '05% off'. '<br/>';
$firstsub = substr( $string1, 4 );
var_dump($firstsub); //results in string(8) "off<br/>"
```

To solve issue you can either strip the `<br/>` (like ozmah recommends) or add it to the if test:

```
if( strtolower( $firstsub ) == 'off<br/>' )
```

Actually what I would do if you don't need it separated you could simply use:

```
if(strpos(strtolower($string1),'off') !== false) { //your code }
```

No need for the `substr()` that way.

Comment: @AmalMurali care to explain why you think it is incorrect?

Comment: Ah, you were right. I had the wrong `charset` in my test script. If you edit the answer, I can remove my downvote. :)

Comment: The problem here is that @AmalMurali thinks "<br/>" in php is interpreted as a whitespace inside the PHP code. I agree completely with you Pitchinnate that the problem is the "<br/>" added after the string.

Comment: @Ozmah: Indeed, it was a mistake on my part. Upvoted this answer to compensate! ;-)

Comment: Lol thanks. At least you were willing to admit you made a mistake, no big deal we all do.

Comment: Although, I think a regex might be in order here. You could remove all the `substr()` calls and use just one single `if (preg_match(...))` and be done with it.

Comment: `preg_` calls are a little slow see updated answer for what I would do.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: Except it'd echo `yes` even for something like `100% sugar-free coffee`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was assuming the format would be similar each time.

Comment: It was an elegant solution what you added at the end @Pitchinnate, get a +1 for that :)

Comment: And the `if(strpos(strtolower($string1),'off') !== false) { //your code }` is the best part of the Answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Through substr you're getting something like `"off<br/>"` instead of what you need because of this:

```
$string1 = '05% off'. '<br/>'
```

Try this to obtain only the "off" word:

```
$firstsub = substr( $string1, 4, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

add `<br>` like this

```
echo $string1 = '05% off';
echo $firstsub = substr( $string1, 4 );
$string1.='<br/>';
```

for me `trim()` is not working